# How to import GetAsyncKeyState in C#?

Tags: c#

To import the `GetAsyncKeyState()` API I'm using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
```

All the web pages gives me the same code, but when I try to compile the compiler throws:

> Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>   The modifier 'extern' is not valid for this item

I'm compiling directly with the command line, but also Visual C# throws the same error. So which is the right way to import the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That means you're putting the declaration in the wrong place of your code.  It needs to be INSIDE a Class, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// not here

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    // not here

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        // put it INSIDE the class

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

        public Form1()
        {

            // not inside methods, though

            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error raised by the compiler is clear. You should put that declaration inside a class:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
   public class MyClass
   {
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
   }
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can find the reference for the `extern` keyword